# Is there a way to "listen" to a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, stream, cursor

Information: using mongoose v4.8.3 (mongo installed yesterday)

I have been performing a case where I want to listen to a mongodb collection. If one should do it, aside, I'd like to try.

I have the current collection with model X. When the method is being called, I want to collect every item in X with a creationDate larger than the current date. After getting all of those results, I want to listen to every entry that get's added to the collection.

```
X.find({ createdOn: { $gt: new Date() } }).tailable().cursor();
```

I thought tailable() would give me the correct result, but it just throws:

"tailable cursor requested on non capped collection"

While looking for solutions, I found that you needed to cap the model to a certain amount... but I am unwilling to do that. Is there a way to just use a mongodb collection as a sort of event bus where the X is persisted and where you could keep listening to new incoming instances of X forever.

Comment: No. Aside from implementing something yourself (for  example a timestamp comparison), I do not think this is easily possible. You could implement a lightweight message queue on MongoDB however, which notifies you of changes.

Comment: I'll look for examples of that then, thx!